# Checking for duplicate and insert only unique item in table but this only works for 1st items

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I'm creating a shopping cart, I want when I add a product to the cart table then only it should insert at one time. So I'm checking duplicate rows using a column product_code in the table, but this only works for 1st item.....If I click another item add to cart button then It does not insert in the table but it shows message item added instead of showing item already added
`

```
 if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $pname = $row['product_name'];
    $pimage = $row['product_image'];
    $pprice = $row['product_price'];
    $pcode = $row['product_code'];
    $pqty = 1;

    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_code FROM cart");
    $stmt2->execute();
    $res = $stmt2->get_result();
    $r = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $code = $r['product_code'];

    if($pcode!=$code){
        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (product_name,product_price,product_image,qty,total_price,product_code) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $query->bind_param("sssiss",$pname,$pprice,$pimage,$pqty,$pprice,$pcode);
        $query->execute();
        $_SESSION['showAlert'] = 'block';
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Item added to your cart!';
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['showAlert'] = 'block';
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Item already added to your cart!';
        header("location:index.php");
    }
}
```

`

Comment: A simple way to manage this would be to have the cart table use a unique key on a user_id and product_id. Then, if there’s a duplicate, the system can either update or ignore.

Comment: @catdog Ossas bro, please google some cart examples with database structure. You have to keep data in cart with user Unique ID to understand which cart belongs to which user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT product.*, cart.product_code FROM product
        inner join cart on product.product_code= cart.product_code
        where cart.person_id=?")
    $stmt ->execute(array($person_id));
    $data = $stmt ->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rows = $stmt ->rowCount();
    if($rows>0){
        $_SESSION['showAlert'] = 'block';
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Item already added to your cart!';
        header("location:index.php");
        exit;
    }
    else{
        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (product_name,product_price,product_image,qty,total_price,product_code) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $query->bind_param("sssiss",$pname,$pprice,$pimage,$pqty,$pprice,$pcode);
        $query->execute();
        $_SESSION['showAlert'] = 'block';
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Item added to your cart!';
        header("location:index.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

i think this code will help you :) I hope there is a person id in the basket

Comment: where i put this code ? $row = $query->rowCount();
if($row)

Comment: I will update it for you to understand better now

Comment: I hope you understand